# A Large Number of sp_counted_impl_p Objects

Tags: c++, boost, smart-pointers

I just performed [Allocation Profiling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/700097/memory-allocation-profiling-in-c/700180#700180) about how many objects of each type are in my application. I am using boost::shared_ptr extensively.

I found a large number of sp_counted_impl_p objects allocated, each occupying 16 bytes. How many of sp_counted_impl_p objects can be expect per shared_ptr? Does someone have an idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For what I can see in the implementation, just one per shared_ptr. However, note that there are more objects used by boost internally, that may use this counted class directly or shared_ptr itself. Also, if you use the boost.serialization framework, it is also based on this class/mechanism. Anyway, by "a large number", how many of them are there?

Comment: hmmm ... I now think I have just one per shared_ptr, but I am collecting a large number of objects! Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

There should be one per object you point to with a `shared_ptr`. If there are more of them, you're probably not using `shared_ptr` properly and you're begging for troubles like double-free errors.

Comment: hmmm ... I now think I have just one per shared_ptr, but I am collecting a large number of objects! I ran valgrind before, which told me atleast I don't have double-free errors. Thanks for your answer, though.