# capture the memory usage of openCV program in the program itself

Tags: c++, opencv, memory

I want to know the RAM utilized by an OpenCV program written in language C++. So, can I capture the memory usage inside OpenCV program itself?. I tried doing it using task manager but I can't achieve it since the program takes just 5 msec to execute.
Thank you.

Comment: I think you can find answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/700097/memory-allocation-profiling-in-c

Answer (score 1):

A simple idea is to make you execution last longer so you have enought time to check it. There are several ways to do it.

```
sleep();
waitKey();
while(1);
```

However, it is allways better to use a profiling tool, e.g. Valgrind.