# How to get size of all allocated heap memory

Tags: c++, c, malloc, heap-memory, new-operator

I'd like to find out how much memory the software has allocated using new/malloc. I don't really want the size of heap, because the allocator is most likely using more than I actually allocated. But I need this to check how much memory a certain part of code has allocated, hence I need an accurate sum of all new & malloc sizes. Any way to do that except for overloading new & malloc?

Comment: There is a wealth of information about memory profiling here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/700097/620382

Comment: No. Just overloading them is the best way to go to be sure.

Comment: I would use a memory monitoring tool like ValGrind or Purify

Comment: @NathanOliver, should we have this phrase copyrated? :)

Comment: @NathanOliver it's of course possible I'm missing something, but in most cases, I found these tools to be unusable due to performance. For some applications (e.g., servers), they cause the control paths to change completely.

Comment: @AmiTavory I did not know that.  I just know they are normally recommended.

Comment: @SergeyA You noticed that eh.

Comment: @Ami Tavory - Why would you be using a memory monitoring tool in a production version of an application anyway?   The main use for such tools is debugging and monitoring, both of which can add significant overhead.

Comment: @Peter Say you have a server, and you have a (very expensive, closed source, and not an infinitely configurable) traffic generator which you use to bombard it with requests. The server shows an accumulated memory leak noticeable after a day of testing. The server runs zillions of modules - and processes, some originating from in-house code, some from open source projects, and some from other origins. I've run into variations of this several times. BTW, some leaks turned out to originate from Python management systems, and CPython's C is not very hackable.

Comment: The thing is, most of these tools and systems focus on detecting memory leaks, but for some reason there's not this basic thing like GetHowMuchMemoryIAllocated() :)...

Answer (score 0):

I have just started with Linux kernel programming. I think it might be useful to debug total memory taken by heap to debug tendency of memory use in various parts of the programme. I understand, that there is lots of useful/powerful tools (e.g. valgrind), which does the job.
But this likely would take more time than necessary. To get a quick grasp I think might be used '&end' global char variable (identifying location of heap start) & 'sbrk(0)' which reports 'program break' address e.g.:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>
extern char end;
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::cout << "heap start: " << (void*)&end << '\n';
    const int RANDSIZE{20};
    void* allocatedPool[RANDSIZE];
    for (int i{0}; i<RANDSIZE; ++i)
    {
         std::cout << "current heap end: " << sbrk(0) << '\n';
         allocatedPool[i] = malloc( RANDSIZE * 4096 );
    }
}
```

NOTE: Looks like malloc call is allocating far more memory, than page due to overhead/optimizations of calculations https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/697960/why-malloc-allocates-more-memory-than-neeed. So I have used '20' as multiplier to get over allocated 'program end' Also, unistd.h header file internally allocates heap, so it won't match '(void*)&end' address.

Programme output:

```
current heap end: 0x55f4e3ce1000
current heap end: 0x55f4e3d07000
current heap end: 0x55f4e3d07000
current heap end: 0x55f4e3d2f000
current heap end: 0x55f4e3d2f000
current heap end: 0x55f4e3d57000
current heap end: 0x55f4e3d57000
current heap end: 0x55f4e3d7f000
current heap end: 0x55f4e3d7f000
current heap end: 0x55f4e3da7000
current heap end: 0x55f4e3da7000
current heap end: 0x55f4e3dcf000
current heap end: 0x55f4e3dcf000
current heap end: 0x55f4e3df7000
current heap end: 0x55f4e3df7000
current heap end: 0x55f4e3e1f000
current heap end: 0x55f4e3e1f000
current heap end: 0x55f4e3e47000
current heap end: 0x55f4e3e47000
current heap end: 0x55f4e3e6f000
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33291923)